# Making an Efficient Calculator Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
  import numpy as np
a='addition'
s='subraction'
m='multiplication'
d='division'
calc=str(input('Would you like addition(a), Subtraction(s), Multiplication(m), or division(d)?'))
if calc =='a':
    num1=int(input(''))
    num2=int(input(''))
    print('num1+num2')
elif calc== 's':
    num1=int(input(''))
    num2=int(input(''))
    print(int(num1-num2))
elif calc=='m':
    num1=int(input(''))
    num2=int(input(''))
    print(int(num1*num2))
elif calc=='d':
    num1=int(input(''))
    num2=int(input(''))
    print(int(num1/num2))
else:
    Print('Please use the letters in paranthesis to indicate the operation')
```

Hello everyone. I'm a beginner and was wondering if I could get some advice on how to add floating numbers and log within my calculator. Currently, if I do a simple calculation (5/2) I get 2 instead of 2.5. Any suggestions or tips on how to go about doing this? Thank you for taking the time to make the suggestion.

Comment: Remove the `int()` call then? `num1/num2` returns a float, it's the `int()` call you are using when printing that causes the value to be truncated. Why are you using `int()` in all your `print()` calls to begin with?

Comment: Use `float()` instead of `int()` would be a good start

Comment: @cricket_007: Why use `float()` **at all** here?

Comment: @Mart I only said it's a start, not the best solution

Comment: @cricket_007: I'd say it's a bad start, only adding more confusion and ignoring the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you're converting your floating numbers to integers, which are only whole numbers, plus you have extra conversions that aren't required, for example, your calc variable doesn't need to convert input to string because by default it returns a string, which is also why you would have to convert your inputs to floats instead of ints

```
import numpy as np
a='addition'
s='subraction'
m='multiplication'
d='division'
calc=input('Would you like addition(a), Subtraction(s), Multiplication(m), or division(d)?')
if calc =='a':
    num1=float(input(''))
    num2=float(input(''))
    print(num1+num2)
elif calc== 's':
    num1=float(input(''))
    num2=float(input(''))
    print(num1-num2)
elif calc=='m':
    num1=float(input(''))
    num2=float(input(''))
    print(num1*num2)
elif calc=='d':
    num1=float(input(''))
    num2=float(input(''))
    print(num1/num2)
else:
    print('Please use the letters in paranthesis to indicate the operation')
```